# When testing a React component with Enzyme is it better to use simulate or to call the method directly on the instance()?

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

If you have a component like this

```
class Editor extends Component {
  handleChange() {
    // some code
  }

  render() {
     <div>
       <input className="Editor" onChange={this.handleChange} />
     </div>
  }
}
```

Is it better to test the handle change by simulating the change event with simulate like this:

> wrapper.simulate('change', { // })

Or by calling the method directly by using instance:

> wrapper.instance().handleChange()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Shallow Rendering](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) then `.simulate` just tries to [find the right prop](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/f9999a71a53e4dc60d277d259bd4419aaa977de1/packages/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js#L9-L82) and [call it](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16.3/src/ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js#L384).  From the [Common Gotchas section for `.simulate`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#common-gotchas):

> Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event, `.simulate()` will in fact target the component's prop based on the event you give it. For example, `.simulate('click')` will actually get the `onClick` prop and call it.

There isn't any advantage to calling `.simulate` when using Shallow Rendering and simply calling the prop directly avoids issues caused by the event not mapping to the correct prop.

---

If you are using [Full DOM Rendering](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) then `.simulate` [will fire an event](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16.3/src/ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js#L303-L308) that ends up calling [`runEventsInBatch`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0e67969cb1ad8c27a72294662e68fa5d7c2c9783/packages/react-dom/src/test-utils/ReactTestUtils.js#L500) from the comically named [`ReactDOM.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.Events`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0e67969cb1ad8c27a72294662e68fa5d7c2c9783/packages/react-dom/src/test-utils/ReactTestUtils.js#L46-L47).

So using `.simulate` with `mount` will actually simulate the event, just note from the [Common Gotchas section](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.md#common-gotchas) that:

> `ReactWrapper` will pass a `SyntheticEvent` object to the event handler in your code. Keep in mind that if the code you are testing uses properties that are not included in the `SyntheticEvent`, for instance `event.target.value`, you will need to provide a mock event...for it to work.

For Full DOM Rendering it is up to you to determine if there is any value in having `ReactDOM` simulate the event to call your handler or to just call your handler directly.

---

From [this post](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/991#issuecomment-313203726) by an Airbnb dev:

> In general, I've found it's best to invoke the prop directly and avoid `.simulate`.

For your test it would look something like this:

```ts
test('onChange', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Editor />);  // works with shallow or mount
  const onChangeHandler = wrapper.find('input').prop('onChange');
  // test onChangeHandler
})
```